# Generate adjacency matrix of undirected graph

Tags: c

An Adjacency matrix of undirected graph is naturally symmetric, a weight of A->B or B->A should be represented symmetrically in the matrix. I've implemented the following code to generated random adjacency matrix of a graph but it turns out it does not take into consideration this property. Would someone suggest me a modification to make it works?

```
        #define INFTY INT_MAX
        int **edge;
        int N=5;

        edge= malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            edge[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        }

        srand(0);
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if(i == j){
                    edge[i][j] = 0;
                }

                else{
                    int r = rand() % 10;
                    edge[i][j] = (r == 5)? INFTY: r;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: The randomization doesn't work? Or what?

Comment: It does but I don't know who to make the matrix symmetric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that a undirected graph has a symmetrical adjacency matrix:

Then simply randomly assign the upper triangle of the matrix, and make the lower triangle match:

```
#define INFTY INT_MAX
int **edge;
int N=5;

edge= malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    edge[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}

srand(0);
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j = i; j < N; j++)
    {
        if(i == j){
            edge[i][j] = 0;
        }

        else{
            int r = rand() % 10;
            int val = (r == 5)? INFTY: r;
            edge[i][j] = val;
            edge[j][i] = val;  // If there is edge from i to j, then there
                               // must be edge from j to i
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes that is right. I have not observed this. Thank you so much.